# Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update a value from `sys.sequences`, before this I create a schema and then a sequence, here is all the code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA Test ;
GO
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.Folio
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

Right now I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
update sys.sequences set current_value = 646
```

But I get this message:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed

I tried doing this:

```
sp_configure 'allow update', 1 
go 

reconfigure with override 
go
```

But I'm still getting the same error, what can I do to solve this? maybe I should change `increment` for `decrement`?

PD. I'm using sql server 2008 express edition.

Comment: Your tag is curious.  I thought sequences were introduced in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alter sequence`:

```
alter sequence set restart with 646
```

Databases do not allow ad hoc changes to the system table for very good reasons!